# SSIS transform rows to columns from xml

Tags: xml, ssis, transpose

I get an xml file from a web appliance stored on a shared file server.  The xml is pooly structured.  Here is an example:

```
<row>
  <cell>2000-01-01T00:00:18.000000</cell> 
  <cell>2012-02-24T14:17:12.000000</cell> 
  <cell>0.18</cell> 
  <cell>3697.26464171841</cell> 
  <cell>3697.26464171841</cell> 
  <cell>3737.1</cell> 
  <cell>10.4318</cell> 
  <cell>0.229</cell> 
</row>
```

Each cell element actually should be a different element.  For example, if I were to contruct this xml sheet i would format it like this:

```
<run>
  <startTime>2000-01-01T00:00:18.000000</startTime> 
  <EndTime>2012-02-24T14:17:12.000000</EndTime> 
  <effeicency>0.18</effeicency> 
  <good>3697.26464171841</good> 
  <bad>3697.26464171841</bad> 
  <average>3737.1</average> 
  <oee>10.4318</oee> 
  <up>0.229</up> 
</run>
```

I am using SSIS XML source to pick this up and get the following:

```
Cell|row_id
2001-01-01|3
2001-01-01|3
0.18|3
3697.264|3
3697.264|3
3737.1|3
10.431|3
0.229|3
2012-01-01|4
2012-01-01|4
0.15|4
698.222|4
397.204|4
337.1|4
11.531|4
0.219|4
... 
...
```

So my question is, can I use some transformation to pivot the data even thought I only have 2 columns in the source and I am not aggragating on anthing?  My expected output would be

```
2001-01-01|   2001-01-01|    0.18|    3697.264|    3697.264|    3737.1|    10.431|   0.229
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution may not be scalable for lots of records, but it work for me with these
kind of headaches.  The key is to navigate the XML using XPath and convert the elements
to the appropriate datatype.

I don't know what the Primary Key would be I'm going to say ApplianceRowID for this example.
So the table structure would be something like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WebApplianceStaging] (
ApplianceRowID [int] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
RowData [nvarchar] (max) NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_ApplianceRowID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [ApplianceRowID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  
   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Write your SSIS import to bring in this data
then either in the SSIS or a stored proc convert the XML data to the appropriate
field types and insert into your final table.

Here I'm using a Common Table Expression and because of the number of decimal places I'm just using floats as the data types and initially making the dates varchar then converting to datetime with a left function and the 126 format specifier.  Because it is XML there is a risk that the value is an empty string so you need to null those fields hence the nullif:

```
;WITH ApplianceRow(RowID, RowDataRaw) as
(
    SELECT ApplianceRowID, RowData 
    FROM WebApplianceStaging
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinalTable]  --Your Final Table
([RowID],[StartTime],[EndTime],[Efficiency],[good],[bad],[average],[oee],[up])
SELECT 
    RowID
    --,RowDataRaw
    --,XML_Encoded
    ,CONVERT(
       DATETIME
       ,LEFT(NULLIF(XML_Encoded.value('/row[1]/cell[1]','varchar(50)'),''),19)
       ,126
      ) AS StartTime
    ,CONVERT(
       DATETIME
       ,LEFT(NULLIF(XML_Encoded.value('/row[1]/cell[2]','varchar(50)'),''),19)
       ,126
      ) AS EndTime
    ,NULLIF(XML_Encoded.value('/row[1]/cell[3]','float'),'') AS efficiency
    ,NULLIF(XML_Encoded.value('/row[1]/cell[4]','float'),'') AS good
    ,NULLIF(XML_Encoded.value('/row[1]/cell[5]','float'),'') AS bad
    ,NULLIF(XML_Encoded.value('/row[1]/cell[6]','float'),'') AS average
    ,NULLIF(XML_Encoded.value('/row[1]/cell[7]','float'),'') AS oee
    ,NULLIF(XML_Encoded.value('/row[1]/cell[8]','float'),'') AS up
FROM ApplianceRow
CROSS APPLY
(
     SELECT XML_Encoded = CAST(RowDataRaw AS XML)
) as XML_Encoded
```